# PHP Postgres Driver 9.2.18 problem with simple select

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I never used postgres with PHP.
Now I'm trying a simple select on a view in Postgres, but I get this error:

```
An error occurred: Syntax Error in SELECT * FROM 02_s3_ct13t_tariffe
```

It seems that the connection is fine (if I run `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables` it works, and I can see in results the table name `02_s3_ct13t_tariffe`).

Instead, if I run this code, I get the error mentioned above:

```
$conn_string = "host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port=xxxx dbname=xxxx user=xxxx password=xxxxxxxx";
$db = pg_connect("$conn_string") or die('connection failed');

//$sql = "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 02_s3_ct13t_tariffe";
$result = pg_query($db, $sql);

if (!$result) {
  $error = pg_last_error($db);
  echo "$error";
  exit;
}
```

Any ideas? how to check privileges or correct syntax to access a table name starting with numbers?

Comment: Can someone explain the reason for the downvote please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose your table in quotes (table names shouldn't start with digits):

```
SELECT * FROM "02_s3_ct13t_tariffe"
```

Better use `pdo_pqsql` instead.

Comment: Schema name is not required, but double quotes are!